# Improperly creating timestamped filenames

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using a raspberry pi and a python script to capture images from a camera connected to the pi. I have a task scheduler that calls the script, and the script make a command line call that interfaces with the camera. I'm trying to have it create a new file titled with the timestamp taken from python's datetime module.

The problem I'm experiencing is that it won't print both. I can create a file with just the date timestamp; I can create one with just the time. When I try to combine both, however, the file isn't created, and I'm not sure why. Is it because the filename ends up being too long?

I've tried numerous variations of the code below:

```
import os

import time
import datetime

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

sys_call = 'fswebcam -r 1280x720 /home/pi/python/projectx_images/%s' %st

os.system(sys_call)
```

I've also tried using `datetime.now()` to no avail. Specifically, if I try either `st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%y-%m-%d')` or `st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%H:%M:%S')` then it works fine, but not with both.

Comment: where are you printing timestamps? Where are two? I only see the `sys_call` that contains *one* timestamp from `st`. When I print `st`, I see `17-11-17_17:44:38`.

Comment: Your quotes don't match -- you start your format strings with `"` and end them with `'`.

Comment: Alternatively, have cron (or whatever your task scheduler is) invoke `fswebcam -r 1280x720 /home/pi/python/projectx_images/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)` and skip your python script altogether.

Comment: What type of filesystem are you writing the file to? FAT filesystems don't like `:` in filenames.

Comment: Your code produces values like `fswebcam -r 1280x720 /home/pi/python/projectx_images/17-11-17_18:08:49`. As @Robᵩ suggested, it could be tone of the characters is illegal in file/folder path. You could also try putting double quotes around the path so it's: `fswebcam -r 1280x720 "/home/pi/python/projectx_images/17-11-17_18:08:49"`.

Comment: @Robᵩ I did it directly as you mentioned, and it works well. Saves code too. Just wish I could give you proper credit!

Comment: I'll post an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using Python is overkill here. Since your task scheduler is probably already invoking a shell when it invokes Python, let's just have the shell do the work.

Use this command for your command scheduler:

```
fswebcam -r 1280x720 /home/pi/python/projectx_images/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming...

```
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') <--- close with " instead of '
```

isn't your problem... I've used the following code and it works for me.

```
ti = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
```

outputs...

`'17-11-18_01:47:48'`

Note:  This outputs in UTC +0:00 so you'd need to apply another operation on it to get it to your timezone.  Since time.time() returns a UNIX epoch time in seconds, you'd need to offset the time by however much faster/slower your timezone is, in relation to UTC +0:00, in seconds.

I.e. if you're in EST time, then you'd apply `utcfromtimestamp()` on `time.time() - 18000` to get the time for your timezone.

```
ti = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time() - 18000).strftime("%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
```